# Does Lorentz's force and magnetic dipole alignment torque explain same or different forces inside an electric motor?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces

As depicted in the image below borrowed from [this page](https://www.animations.physics.unsw.edu.au/jw/electricmotors.html) the motion of the rotor in an electric motor can be explained by appealing to the Lorentz force on a current carrying wire (left side) or by the orienting torque of a magnetic dipole in a magnetic field (right side).

Do these two explanations describe two separate forces that are accumulated when calculating the torque of a motor or are they just differently framed descriptions of the same underlying force?
[image: Image electric motor principles]

Comment: I hope I'm not one of those from your profile page ;-)

Comment: :-) The fact that you had something constructive to contribute means definitely not, that profile update was triggered by a completely separate subset of the SE community - let's just call them the hall monitors.

Answer (score 1):

I had hoped to see answers to your question, but since this is not the case, I allow my own answer here.

*The torque in your left image can be explained as follows:*

- Electrons have a magnetic dipole moment. In a wire without an external magnetic field, the magnetic dipoles of the electrons are randomly oriented.
- When the electrons are in a magnetic field, their magnetic fields get aligned with the external field, and the loop behaves like the magnet in your right picture. It rotates (clockwise) and comes to rest with the wires close to the poles. The magnetization of the wire depends from the [susceptibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_susceptibility#Volume_susceptibility) of the wires material.
- When a small current is switched on, the Lorentz force acts against the magnetic alignment and the wires move slightly away from the vertical position. What you observe is that the movement of the electrons within an external magnetic field is responsible for the lateral movement of the wire. The Lorentz force acts against magnetic alignment.
- When more electrical power is used, the rotor starts to rotate.

So

> Do these two explanations describe two separate forces that are accumulated when calculating the torque of a motor ...

is the right answer.

Comment: Am I correct in interpreting from your answer that there are two separate terms contributing to the motors torque? Could you provide any further information on the formulas involved?

Comment: Dear sarcastic man (this again refers to your profile), my knowledge is limited to very basic questions of physics. I am more familiar with basic concepts of electromagnetism than with mathematics. Any - as in ever case - Wikipedia gives the first step to the right calculation.